# Transform element to fit height (Angular, SCSS)

Tags: html, css, angular

I am writing a component that accepts a `TemplateRef` as in `@Input()` and renders it at some location within the component. The template appears in a container `div` that has a given width and height that don't necessarily match the aspect ratio of the template. My goal is to stretch (distort) the template to fit the container.

```
<div class="box-content box-background box-template-container">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="boxTemplate; context: { box: box }">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

I found what is necessary in the SCSS to make this work:

```
.box-template-container {
    > ::ng-deep * {
        transform-origin: top left;
        transform: scale(1, 2);
    }
}
```

The problem is this only works when the container is twice as high as the template, so I need to make the `2`dynamic somehow. That's what I am looking for and cannot find. The challenge is the `::ng-deep` partm the scale value is something I could calculate in a function.

Does anyone know how to do this or knows a better way of doing it?

I created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-44bnhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) to demonstrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what supposed to be inside the template but in general the approach feels wrong.

Probably something like this should be just enough:

```
.box-template-container::ng-deep > * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

or more complex:

```
.box-template-container {
  position: relative;
}

.box-template-container::ng-deep > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand how it feel strange, but I really need to distort (squeeze, stretch) the template element. At the moment, I am using SVGs as the templates but it could be an image, too.

Comment: Would be great if you could replicate the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nctqxk) and post the link.

Comment: Done, check original post please :)

Comment: Since the `<svg>` tag is not just an image you’re going to need to explicitly define its aspect ratio. I've [modified your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x8mgxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) to demonstrate how the solution above and `preserveAspectRatio="none"` will cover both cases: img and svg tags.